# Plot sklearn RandomForestRegressor as a single tree

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, graphviz, decision-tree

I know that it is possible to show individual decision trees from a Random Forest using export_graphviz, but is it possible to display the entire forest the same way?

Because, as I understand it, the output of a random forest is well-defined - that is, for any given input it will deterministically output a prediction based on an average over all the trees - shouldn't it be possible to create a new tree which represents the prediction of the entire forest and display that?